# What is a life CV ?

Tags: resume

What is a life CV compared to a regular CV? I have been asked to submit a life CV with my job application. What information would I need to include in a life CV?

Comment: How about asking the people who asked you?

Comment: You need to clarify with the people who made the request. It's a given that resumes are targeted to the category of positions you are going for. I take it that a life resume comprises much more and that they want to know much more about you. The question is: what do they want the life resume to be targeted at, that you are a well rounded person who has volunteer activities on top of everything else and hobbies like being a drummer in a rock band, or that you have had several careers before you went for this position? Ask them what they want from you in terms of the contents of that life resume

Comment: For one employer I encountered, what they really meant with Life CV was basically a CV with everything I did - unrelated temp jobs, skills and hobbies. Nowadays, most employers expect a 'professional CV', which only includes relevant skills, experience and education.

Answer (score 5):

Given that a CV (curriculum vitae) already includes the word "life" because it means something like "the flow of life" in latin, I'd say a "life CV" is redundant.

The [web](http://de.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Life+CV) found this definition:

> A "Life CV" attains less to professional achievements and more to personal ones as a record of the momentous occasions in one's life.
>   It could relate to conquering fears, taking risks, performing incredible feats. All ultimately relating to improving oneself and building character.

So maybe you should ask your employer what exactly he needs (or if you should submit a normal CV, too).

Comment: Yep, the hiring manager or HR contact are either ignorant of things they should really know or believe they're too hip and cool for regular CVs and need employees with Character™.